# nginx config for ember.js/rails/passenger using history api

Tags: ember.js, nginx, passenger

I have an nginx configuration which is correctly serving up index.html no matter what URL the user goes to. For example if the user goes to: myapp.example.com/foo/bar, nginx correctly serves index.html, so that ember.js can handle the /foo/bar route.

But I also need nginx to hand off urls that start with /api to my rails application. This is my current config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name myapp.example.com;
  root /home/app/myapp/current/public;

  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_user app;
  passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby2.2;

  location /api/ {
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?/$request_uri;
  }

}
```

The server (nginx, not rails) returns 404 when ember.js makes any API requests. What should I be putting into the location /api/ section or what else should I change?

Answer (score 1):

Moving the passenger options to the location /api section seems to have worked, like this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name myapp.example.com;
  root /home/app/myapp/current/public;

  location /api/ {
    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_user app;
    passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby2.2;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?/$request_uri;
  }

}
```